# need some explanation regarding basic relations query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, relation

```
CREATE (_1:`Person` { `name`:"Node A" })
 CREATE (_2:`Person` { `name`:"Node B" })

MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person) 
WHERE a.name = 'Node A' AND b.name = 'Node B' 
CREATE a-[r:RELTYPE { name : a.name + '<->' + b.name }]->b 
RETURN r
```

I dont understand the

```
CREATE a-[r:RELTYPE { name : a.name + '<->' + b.name }]->b
```

we create a node with `a` yet we are using `r` to retrieve it?  also what is `<->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `CREATE a-[r:RELTYPE { name : a.name + '<->' + b.name }]->b` doesn't create node `a`, it creates a relationship. The `MATCH ... WHERE` clause retrieves two existing nodes and binds them to `a` and `b`. Then a relationship is created between them and bound to `r`. This relationship is given a property called `name` and this property is assigned a value from a string concatenation of the name properties of node `a` and node `b` with the string literal `<->` in between (the value will in this case resolve to `Node A<->Node B`, which is probably not a very useful property value).

I don't know where you got that code snippet from. It's a bit weird but I suppose it's not really part of answering your question to go into that.